# the grunt serve command freeze after I added material-design-icons

Tags: macos, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

the grunt serve command freeze after I added material-design-icons

```
Running "concurrent:ionic" (concurrent) task
Running "ionic:serve" (ionic) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

I'm on mac osx.

I saw articles saying:

On most systems the maximum number of watches that can be created per user is limited to 8192. watchdog needs one per directory to monitor. To change this limit, edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add:
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384

but it does not help.

I have a basic setting (I keep the bower_components folder outside of app but I copy it inside of www during the dist task:

```
/app
/app/images
/app/styles
/app/index.html
/bower_components
....
/www
/www/bower_components
/www/images
/www/styles
/www/index.html
```

my watch part look like this

```
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep', 'newer:copy:app']
  },
  html: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html'],
    tasks: ['newer:copy:app']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:copy:app', 'newer:jshint:all']
  },
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.styles %>/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer', 'newer:copy:tmp']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js'],
    tasks: ['ngconstant:development', 'newer:copy:app']
  }
},
```